# Issue with index.js.erb in Railscasts 102 (autocomplete): Data isn't showing up in listings.js on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, autocomplete

Rails 3.2.5 app. Very simple, only one model: listing

Has the columns website, url, doctor, comments, and date.

Exactly 9 minutes into the episode he goes to localhost:3000/cateogories.js and the categories pop up on the page in list form.

In my case it would be listings.js

I am getting no errors in the JS console, the browser is just blank. In my terminal it says

*Started GET "/listings.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-10 13:20:41 -0500

Processing by ListingsController#index as JS

Rendered listings/index.js.erb (0.1ms)

Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)*

My index.js.erb file (which, correct me if I'm wrong), goes in views/listings and the code for that is:

```
<%= auto_complete_result @listings, :website %>
```

I'd like to have the autocomplete set up for :url, :website, :comments and :doctor, but that is not my main concern right now. Just want to get it working.

My index in listings_controller.rb is

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.search(params[:search_text]) 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end
end
```

My application.html.erb file includes

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

And I'm not sure if that's necessary in rails 3.2 (it was listed in the railscasts though, which is a little older).

Any idea why localhost:3000/listings.js is blank (I have 5 listings in the database)? Any input is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with just all listings:

```
def index
  @listings = params[:search_text].nil? ? Listing.all : Listing.search(params[:search_text])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end
end
```

I think because you are using search, you can't just go to the page and see results without a `params[:search_text]` of course this depends no how you are handing `search` method. You can handle it by checking for param, but it would be better to handle it in your search implementation instead. Code above should work though.

Comment: Ok yeah that worked, now the search functionality is screwed up. Give me a few here and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Reason why it works in the video is because he is searching using LIKE with wildcards on each side of the param, %term%, if his term is nil, it finds all records, but in your case it finds none. See updated answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Damn thanks for updating the code, definitely helpful! Alright so now the search is working correctly (for the most part), and data is showing up when I go to localhost:3000/listings.js (it's not pretty though, as it is in his Railscasts). See image here: http://i.imgur.com/b590x.png . Alright gonna keep toying with this and try and get through the episode. Will check back in soon. Thanks for the help so far :) And good lookin on the ternary: been a while since I've used that!

Comment: I think this is tricky bc I don't have a form partial. This is in index.html.erb: `<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :listing, :website %>` returns an error of **No route matches {:action=>"auto_complete_for_listing_website", :controller=>"listings"}**. If I add `<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :listing, :website, { :size => 15 }, { :url => formatted_websites_path(:js), :method => :get, :param_name => 'search' } %>` I get an error of: **undefined method `formatted_websites_path'**. Here's a gist of index.html.erb: thoughts? https://gist.github.com/3868048

Comment: Your :url should be just listings_path(:js) or whatever it is in your routes file. Try: rake routes | grep listing and use whatever path is corresponds to your listings index action plus _path(:js)

Comment: Yup understood. So now it's not breaking but the CSS got screwed up a little bit (not worried will fix later), but I think the issue lies somewhere in localhost:3000/listings.js?search=doctor or whatever word you decide to put there. Like I said 3000/listings.js is returning what it should (in this case, the websites...:website) but the search isn't working. So I think the issue lies there (as now the search function isn't working whatsoever): it just keeps returning all 5 results no matter what I type in.

Comment: make sure that you are using the same search param name, it looks like you are using params[:search] but the answer above checking for params[:search_text], just switch it to use :search instead.

Comment: Right right. Got that sorted out. Now it's working fine when I do localhost:3000/listings.js?search=doc or whatever the word is, but now the search on the index page is broken. Been at this all day, going to get groceries, be back in a bit. I really appreciate your help so far :)

Comment: It might be easier to post your code on github at this point :)